# Why are now sf2 crud's views files under app/Resources/views/entityName?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, crud

I just started a new project with sf2 ( 2.8 ) and i noticed that when generating a crud with `doctrine:generate:crud`, twig files are no longer under `src/VendoreName/MyBundle/Resources/views/entityName` but under `app/Resources/views/entityName`.

I can't find any infos about this.
Anyone knows why ?
Is it something i do wrong ? 
Any chance i can get the old behavior back ?

Thanks.
Ludo

Comment: Can you post the exact parameters you were using?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because of the "new" [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#structuring-the-application): having one bundle (AppBundle) per application (as long as you don't develop shared bundles etc).